# Encrypt username and message with public key aes-256

Tags: java, encryption, aes, public-key

I want to encrypt both username and a message with my public key (pubk) with aes-256. I have a code in java, but I think it is incorrect in the first line

```
String str=message+username;
byte[] byte1= str.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] byte2= encrypt(pubk, byte1);

public byte[] encrypt(PublicKey key, byte[] plaintext)
{
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");   
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);  
return cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
}
```

Comment: I want to encrypt both username and password with public key and I don't know if it is correct

Comment: What is special about "username and password" (relative to any other data)? What is your specific goal? Why do you think "encrypt with public key aes-256" is the correct way to do it? What makes you believe that the first line (`String str=password+username;`) is incorrect? IMO, the question is not currently answerable; please spend some time to focus it and try to make it as specific as possible, as well as include a description of what you have tried so far. That should make it more answerable.

Comment: You should not encrypt passwords. You should securely hash them.

Comment: Sorry, it's mistake. I want to encrypt both username and a message with public key